# Split text files at 5000 characters limit

Tags: python, split

I am new to Python and want to split a large number of text files that exceed 5000 characters. Although I run the following code and it does create the outputs files, there is a bug:

The files with more than 5000 characters get split but skipped in the destination directory; If the file 026.txt is to be split, the output_26.txt file is skipped but the remaining characters (from 5001 onwards) are copied into output_27.txt, no problem. Take a look at the screenshot:

[Directory of split files missing output_26.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdq4T.jpg)

Take a look at the code:

```
import os
import codecs

directory = 'path/to/directory'
n = 5000
split_strings = []
file_counter = 1
split_files = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        for index in range(0, len(text), n):
            split_strings.append(text[index: index + n])
        f.close()

    for i in split_strings:
        file_counter = split_strings.index(i)

    with codecs.open("output_" + str(file_counter) + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as o:
        o.write(i)
        o.close()
        file_counter += 1

    if len(text) >= n:
        split_files.append(filename)

print(split_files)
print("Total split files: {}".format(len(split_files)))
```

What is missing from the code?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for i in split_strings` loop?  It assigns `file_counter` but then on the next loop it is immediately reassigned, replacing the previous value.  When the loop finishes, `file_counter` will only be the final value that was assigned.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is a very good point! It wasn't intentional; the `for i in split_strings` loop was added later, but I forgot to delete the line where `file counter` is reassigned. Thanks for pointing it out although it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code, that way you can find out exactly where the code takes a wrong turn.

Comment: It may be easier for others to help you if you can pare down this code and your input data even further. For instance, can you set n = 10 and run a single file with 25 characters and show the contents of each file? Other advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatthewCox that's what I did; I found [a snippet for splitting strings](https://pythonexamples.org/python-split-string-into-specific-length-chunks/) and tried to implement it in my code. I'm running it in just the first 30 files because I know that files 027.txt and 030.txt need splitting. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging each line of the code, I spotted what was wrong about it: the `with` block for writing the new file should have been nested into the `for` loop that comes right before it.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import codecs

directory = 'path/to/directory'
n = 5000
split_strings = []
file_counter = 1
split_files = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        for index in range(0, len(text), n):
            split_strings.append(text[index: index + n])
        f.close()

for i in split_strings:
    file_counter = split_strings.index(i)
    with codecs.open("output_" + str(file_counter) + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as o:
        o.write(i)
        o.close()
        file_counter += 1

if len(text) >= n:
    split_files.append(filename)

print(split_files)
print("Total split files: {}".format(len(split_files)))
```

Thank you everyone for taking the time to post comments!